# Lighttpd Stops Responding, Has to Be Restarted

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, lighttpd

Lighttpd web server, lighttpd was shutting down with the error:

```
[note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
```

I updated to the newest build of lighttpd, updated fd limits, and now lighttpd does not shut down, but occasionally just stops responding. Needs to be restarted to get working again. I'm not really seeing corresponding errors in error.log or anything helpful in access.log. However, I'm seeing a lot of these two errors in the error.log.

```
(connections.c.291) SSL: 1 error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
(mod_evhost.c.317) No such file or directory /srv/sites/www/www/
```

I am up against a Google wall now, so looking for suggestions on what these errors might point to, any other logs I should be looking at, reasons why lighttpd would stop responding but not shut down, any ideas?

Comment: > I updated to the newest build of lighttpd Which version is that? The latest lighttpd release is lighttpd 1.4.51. Please try with lighttpd 1.4.51. Unfortunately, the lighttpd 1.4.45 in Ubuntu will be 2 years old in a few months (January).

Comment: Yes, it was 1.4.45. I have made a lot of progress on this since, updating the PHP version seems to have dealt with this issue.